# How to apply MaterialDesignInXAML to only one control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I want to use the MaterialDesignInXAML for some elements of my WPF application, but i don't want to apply the theme to the whole apps (i'm particularly interested in the buttons)

So how do use the theme without applying this to App.xaml:

```
<Application . . . >
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: When displaying something, WPF's code does roughly this check looking for Templates and the like to apply: 1) Is there a explicit template for it? Use that 2) Is there a Template targetting the type? Use that 3) Does it have Draw Code? Use that 4) If all before failed, call ToString() and display that string | What you want is a case 1. But personally I really like case 2 and it might be the right tool for you.

Answer (score 3):

You Should Add `ResourceDictionary` lines in your `UserControl`

```
<Button x:Class="MyButton">
<Button.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

and use `MyButton`

```
<MyButton></MyButton>
```

Comment: and just in case if you want to remove the MD styling from a particular control, for example from a `ToolBar` you can use ```<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" />```

Answer (score 1):

Only reference the button resources: *MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml*:

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

All the styles are not implicit and must be referenced explicitly as `{StaticResource}`. You can check the [source file on GitHub](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml) to know which styles (keys) are available.